# How do I hide "GNOME Desktop" text that appears on Ubuntu 18.04 Top Panel?

Tags: 18.04, panel, gnome-shell

I want to know how can I remove the "GNOME Desktop" text from top panel.

[image]

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, after disabling the "Unite" Gnome-Extension the top bar text finally removed.

Comment: Please post that info as an answer below. It's totally fine to answer and accept your own question : )

Answer (score 0):

The "**GNOME Desktop**" text is due to a [GNOME shell extension](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75530/how-do-i-install-and-manage-gnome-shell-extensions) named "[Unite](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1287/unite/)". The text appears when you don't have any open windows on your desktop just like the "Ubuntu Desktop" text on Unity (the Unite extension is supposed to mimic Unity).

Disabling the Unite extension gets rid of the text.

---

Source: [Comment by OP](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1048402/how-do-i-hide-gnome-desktop-text-that-appears-on-ubuntu-18-04-top-panel#comment1711273_1048402) (which should have been posted as an answer instead)

Comment: I have Unite installed in my machine and i don't have the text mentioned, i have Dash To Dock, Workspaces to Dock and some more extensions than hide te text. I this that will be better to found one extension that hide the Text (that can be configured in Unte) instead of disable/uninstall all the extension.

Answer (score 0):

Unite now allows you to set the text. Just go to Unite extension settings and clear out the 'Top bar desktop name text' field.